# RE: Project Euler 1:Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000 comments

Tags: ruby

I see a lot of people saying that the sum of all the multiples of 3 and 5 up to 1000 being one sum and others saying another. Some include the multiples of 15, some don't. So, What is it in reality?

```
(1..1000).to_a.each do |i|
  num = []
  if i % 3 == 0
    num << i
    p num
  elsif i % 5 == 0
    num << i
    p num
  end
end
```

I know there is a better way to code this but when i run this code I don't get repeats. meaning no two 15s
So why would we have to subtract it?
just wondering.

Comment: Subtract what? State your question clearly.

Comment: @sawa if you re-read the the question you'll notice i had mentioned only one example to which this post is about. repeating the multiples of 15s to which the multiples of 3 and 5 eventually overlap. so would you agree that you misread it perhaps?

Comment: No I won't. Why should I?

Answer (score 2):

Building upon the original problem statement from project euler which is less ambiguous:

> If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23. Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

This means "multiples of either 3 or 5", which naturally includes multiples of 15 one or the other way around. However, your code will not work, because

- the `num` variable is reset to an empty array on every iteration. You should instead initialize the variable outside of the loop
- No need to store the numbers in an array, we can directly compute the sum.
- `1..1000` will iterate up to the number `1000` whereas the problem clearly wants us to find "all the multiples of 3 or 5 **below** 1000". You can achieve that with an exclusive range `1...1000` (three dots) or by writing `1..999`. This should be the primary reason why you get the wrong result.
- `to_a` is not necessary.
- you can combine the conditionals with `||`, so you dont have to write the identical inner code twice.

All of this leads to

```
sum = 0
(1...1000).each do |i|
  if i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0
    sum += i
  end
end
```

For a more functional-ish approach you could rewrite this as follows:

```
(1...1000).select {|x| x % 3 == 0 || x % 5 == 0 }.inject(:+)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. and Yes the like i said the original code could have done better and proved it right. In sum to all, we do have to include 15s 30s and so forth, where the 3s and 5s overlap.